# What is the closest solution to Microsoft Visio with Latex text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I'd like to have a program where I can model diagrams like in Microsoft Visio and write math formulas in Latex on it. It would be nice to see the rendered formulas (which can be edited in some way, i.e. double clicking) and be able to move around everything by dragging and dropping.

(Rendering just the boxes from Visio and writing Latex on it is not really a user-friendly option for me)

Is there anything like this for LaTeX?

Comment: Use inkscape with textext add on.

Comment: I would say Ipe

Comment: The _classic_ for this is [XFig](http://xfig.org/userman/). Well, one  has to get accustomed to it's 80s-unixy GUI style (you need to install an X server to run it...). But it is an extremely mature and still very powerful piece of software.

Comment: @HarishKumar, that looks really nice (and also the closest the OP is likely to get to an answer).  It looks like a little bit of work getting texttext to work on the latest inkscape though.

Comment: @ChrisH: [You mean this?](https://dgleich.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/fixing-textext-on-inkscape-for-windows/)

Comment: @HarishKumar, yes, I'm working through it now, but not without further problems.  It would be much easier under Linux but my work machine is windows :(.

Comment: @ChrisH [It shouldn't be that hard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iAWXf.png)

Comment: @HarishKumar, inkscape 0.91 needs some mods to textex, plus dependency issues in the python interpreter included with inkscape are harder to resolve when you have a different version of python 2 installed on the same machine.  I'm buried in gtk dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions. Here's a summary - feel free to edit it with other options:

- Inkscape + textext extension
- Ipe
- Xfig

I went with Ipe because it's really user friendly.

**Update:**

I recently started using **draw.io** - it's much easier and has a lot of prefabricated shapes.

Comment: **Ipe** is excellent!

Comment: **IPE** is very useful. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not too familiar with Microsoft Visio, but another option might be the web app [draw.io](https://www.draw.io). It's a nice diagramming tool that interfaces with Google Drive and other services, and supports export to `png`, `svg`, and `pdf`.

Draw.io [supports MathJax](http://bit.ly/1cn0fwl) for mathematical typesetting.

Comment: That looks great too!